# Record bypassing sharing setting

Tags: community

I have created a sharing setting, which is restricting the one country user to see the data of other country , Every record is working fine but only one Account is created which is visible to all users , can any one let us know the reason for this. thanks :)

Comment: From that account click the "sharing" button. This may require you to add the button to the page layout. Post a screenshot of that page for us and we can probably tell you what the issue is.

Comment: To be able to help here, your sharing rule and the record in consideration needs to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Your Account may not have the field populated with what your sharing setting is set to. Alternatively, you could recalculate the sharing rules. Sharing Settings -> Recalculate to see if it works.